# How can I detect when a forked xterm has been exited (perl RHEL6)?

Tags: perl, fork

In perl on RHEL6, I need to detect when an xterm running in a forked process has been exited by the user of that xterm.

Here's some code that demonstrates the problem...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;

my $fork_stat = do_fork_sub();
print "fork_stat: ${fork_stat}\n";

exit;

sub do_fork_sub {

    my $pid = fork();

    if($pid == 0) {

        my $cmd = "xterm; tcsh &";
        system($cmd);

        # When system command above finishes, the xterm is done, exit
        # this child process...
        exit;
    }

    for(;;) {

        # If something happened in the xterm that 
        # created file "child_complete_flag", return "SUCCESS".
        if(-e "child_complete.flag") {return("SUCCESS");}

        # If the user of the xterm gave up on the work by exiting,
        # return "FAILED".  
        my $pid_srch_cmd = "ps uax | awk '{print \$2}' | grep ${pid}";
        print "-I- searching for pid using...  ${pid_srch_cmd}\n";
        my $fork_pid_alive = `${pid_srch_cmd}`;    

        if(!($fork_pid_alive)) {
        print "Detected end of xterm proc\n";
            return("FAILED");
        }

    sleep(3);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work.  If I exit the xterm, the forked process persists anyway.  I tried sticking a system call to a "kill -9" of $$ after the system call that creates the xterm.  No luck.

Any suggestions welcome.

---

In response to one of the questions I was asked below....

"What else does the parent need to do? Also, the way you have it the do_fork_sub blocks for as long as that work in xterm takes. Is that intended? What is the purpose of the whole program?"

The example above is a greatly simplified version of what's really happening.  In that world, the xterm does a -e and runs a tool that can take a long time to run, days sometimes.  If it finishes successfully, I want the parent to detect this (parses this info from a log file), return from the subroutine where the next step will start (another 2-3 days).  What I don't want to do is wait around for the user to exit the xterm in that case.  If the tool passed, declare success and move on.  Thus the purpose of the parent sitting around looking at the child.

The tool that runs in the xterm may also fail.  In that case, email is sent to the user a and they eventually go to the xterm and try to debug the problem. WHen ready to try again, they start the tool again and let it run in the xterm (2-3 more days).  If it passes... see above.  But, it may fail again.  If they eventually just give up, they will "exit" out of the xterm.  In that case, I want to detect this and return from the subroutine with a "FAILED" status.

I am playing with $SIG(CHLD) = 'IGNORE' and = 'DEFAULT', seeing if I can control the fate of forked process once it exits.  Rather than let it become a zombie, I would rather it just die so that the parent can detect it's death and act accordingly.  It seems sensitive to me setting the $SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE' if I place it before the fork().  If I exit the xterm, the child process dies, the parent detects it, and everything acts accordingly.  But unfortunately, the child process seems to die on it's own.  It looks like the parent's call to "system("xterm")" doesn't wait for the xterm to complete and the whole thing just dies prematurely.

Comment: 1. Call `exec` instead of `system` with a *single* executable and without `&`. 2. Install a `$SIG{CHLD}` handler to detect termination of the child process more reliably and efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for the response ~  I tried exec vs system.  No difference.  I also got rid of the &.  This seemed to make the parent.pl proc uninterruptable.  Not sure I understand the %SIG hash or how to use in this context. Reading up on that now.

Comment: What else does the parent need to do?  Also, the way you have it the `do_fork_sub` blocks for as long as that work in xterm takes.  Is that intended? What is the purpose of the whole program?

Comment: You should also read the `system` and `exec` documentation. `system` does another fork/exec and if the command contains shell metacharacters, the command is executed via the shell, resulting in a third fork before `xterm` is launched. `$pid` will only contain the PID of the `xterm` process with `exec('xterm')`. Not sure what `tcsh` is supposed to do. Maybe you want `exec('xterm', '-e', 'tcsh')`?

Comment: Regarding the question... What else does the parent need to do?, I will elaborate in the body of the question (easier there).

Comment: Alright, thanks for the update. It brings further questions. First, the `xterm -e` that you now mention differs crucially from the example: It exits when what it **e**xecutes finishes (on my system anyway).  So your `xterm` will be gone, whether the job did well or not.  How is the user going to "_go to the xterm and try to debug the problem_"?  Second, cannot the parent establish both success/failure by parsing that log?  There are a number of things you can do but I am not sure what exactly is happening. For one, `exec` the program and in the parent `waitpid` and then parse the log.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it's not elegant, but the answer I came up with was to pass an "echo ..." statement to the xterm invocation which uniquely identifies it in the output of "ps aux".  For example...

$cmd = "xterm -e \"echo 'This string is unique'; tcsh\" &"
Then system($cmd);

Then just grep the output of "ps aux" for the unique string && maybe "xterm" && perhaps the user... whatever it takes.